# How does QuickCheck detect datatypes?

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

If we define a function like this

```
fun :: Int -> Property
```

and then run

```
quickCheck fun
```

The quickCheck starts generating random data of type Int. The question is how does quickCheck detect that the argument datatype of fun is Int and not any other datatype?  If I make the question more general I should ask that if we have a function called fun like this

```
fun :: datatype_1 -> datatype_2 -> ... -> datatype_n -> Property
```

How does quickCheck detect the type of each individual datatype_1, datatype_2, ... and datatype_n? And also how does it detect how many arguments the function fun takes?

Comment: It does not have to detect that, it simply constraints it to an instance of `Arbitrary`.

Comment: As for the number of data types. In Haskell, every function takes *exactly* one parameter. It thus uses some sort of recursion to recurse on the function that is returned out of that function, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Roughly, this is how type classes work. One can declare

```
class C a where
   foo :: a -> Bool
```

and then

```
instance C (Int -> Bool) where
   foo f = f 42
instance C (String -> Bool) where
   foo f = f "hello"
instance C (String -> [Int]) where
   foo f = sum (f "hello") > 42
```

and so on.

This has the apparent effect to make `foo` "detect" the type of its argument `f` and act accordingly. Actually, what happens is that Haskell performs type inference, during which the appropriate instance is selected -- at compile time. At runtime, no "type detection" happens; indeed, types are erased after compilation, and there is no type information available at runtime, so it would be impossible to detect which type `f` belongs to.

The actual QuickCheck mechanism is much more complex, of course. To handle functions with an arbitrary number of arguments, a set of "recursive" `instance`s is used, handling each argument every "recursive call", so to speak. This is a rather tricky technique, also used in `printf` and other "variadic" functions. If you are unfamiliar with type classes, I do not recommend to start learning them from such a complex trick.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, but [this is the instance](https://github.com/nick8325/quickcheck/blob/62e32e099cac456b088407bbe70d33e0b03fd75e/Test/QuickCheck/Property.hs#L176) you're looking for in the current implementation.

```hs
instance (Arbitrary a, Show a, Testable prop) => Testable (a -> prop) where
  property f =
    propertyForAllShrinkShow arbitrary shrink (return . show) f
  propertyForAllShrinkShow gen shr shw f =
    -- gen :: Gen b, shr :: b -> [b], f :: b -> a -> prop
    -- Idea: Generate and shrink (b, a) as a pair
    propertyForAllShrinkShow
      (liftM2 (,) gen arbitrary)
      (liftShrink2 shr shrink)
      (\(x, y) -> shw x ++ [show y])
      (uncurry f)
```

As @chi correctly stated, there is recursion happening here. The recursive call is `propertyForAllShrinkShow` calling `propertyForAllShrinkShow`, and by calling `uncurry`, a property in the form `a -> b -> c -> Bool` gets turned into `(a, b) -> c -> Bool`. As `(a, b)` is a valid arbitrary because there is an `instance` of `Arbitrary (a, b)`, the same instance of `Testable` will run again where `prop` is `c -> Bool`. Then, the same will run again as `((a, b), c`, and `prop` will then be just `Bool`. At that point, the [`Bool` instance of `Testable`](https://github.com/nick8325/quickcheck/blob/62e32e099cac456b088407bbe70d33e0b03fd75e/Test/QuickCheck/Property.hs#L135) kicks in, which uses the default `propertyForAllShrinkShow`, which creates the actual application of `f x`. So another way to say it is that quickcheck generates all of the values at the same time as an arbitrary tuple and uses recursion in the `instance` of `Testable` to construct the tuple.